# Compare specific fields of two nodes side-by-side

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I have a content type consisting of 15 large text areas fields.

I would like to be able to select specific fields (or maybe just one for start) and **review the content of two nodes side-by-side** with the selected fields aligned horizontally (in a table maybe). Also these fields should be available for inline edit using the [Editable Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) module, so I need this to be done inside a view which would allow me to use the `editable` field formatter.

I've checked the [Node Compare](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_compare) module which is great, but it doesn't allow the user to check which fields he'd like to review side-by-side. I need to be able to filter those by exposed filters or something. Furthermore [Node Compare](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_compare) uses a custom view that doesn't allow me to use the `editable` formatter.

Any ideas how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Install and configure [Node Compare](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_compare) module.

[image]

Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> The module to provide node comparison functionality on user request.
>   It compares the values ​​of the fields of nodes.

Comment: Sorry for this, I was still editing. Please review my question. I've tried the Node Compare but it doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: Hey node compare should work, I am attaching the screenshot for the same.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to reveal the field filter to the user? (for example to be able to tick, which fields I'd like to compare). As far I can see, I can only configure this statically from module settings..

Comment: Also by using Node Compare I'm unable to edit the content of the fields inline with the Editable Fields module, as it doesn't allow me to set a field formatter like a regular view would.

Comment: @LePhleg then why not create 2 block views? and put them side by side on a page.

Comment: @Sssweat because the fields won't be aligned and also this way I think I'll need two identical sets of exposed filters..

Comment: @Sssweat do you have any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

A thoroughly complicated problem since node compare isn't an option. Entity forms, entity reference and field permissions could do it though.

Of the top of my head I'd start with an entity reference form that allows you to pick all the nodes to compare.. Then when the form is saved, use rules to create a redirect to a view passing the required nids as contextual filters in the url in your edit view. This will limit the view to those nodes.

For only one field at a time, you could create 15 different views and a taxonomy field in the entity reference form to control which view it redirects to.

Or for many fields at the same time, have one view and use the field permissions module. Have a role per field and then apply (actually take away) roles based on which taxonomy terms the user selected in the entity reference form. Then only those fields will appear in the view.

You'd need another rule that would give the user the those roles back at some point.

I'd love to see some other solutions without custom coding.

Comment: Interesting workflow for a strictly non-custom implementation. I'll give it a shot, if no other suggestion would come up soon..